# Does Android Things support Room Database?

Tags: android-room, android-things

I am migrating an existing app running on *Android* and is working on its migration to *Raspberry Pi*. Just wondering if it's possible to directly migrate the usage of *Room* database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't see any obstacles against using *Room* on *Android Things* which is just a [library "wrapping" *SQLite*](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room).

If interested, here is a list of [Android features not currently supported by Android Things devices](https://developer.android.com/things/get-started/platform-differences#apis).